# ArgumentError when using Devise and has_secure_password together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I had a working model prior to adding Devise gem. After I installed Devise and ran `rails generate devise User`, I started having this error.

Whenever I go to rails console and typed

`User.first`

or

`User.create(username: "Iggy1", email: "iggy1@gmail.com", password: "helloworld", password_confirmation: "helloworld")`

It always returns

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:146:in `password_digest'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `block in serializable_hash'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `each'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/serialization.rb:108:in `serializable_hash'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:17:in `serializable_hash'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:114:in `serializable_hash'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:120:in `inspect'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I kept getting `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error. I can understand it returns argument error for `create` method (maybe I specified less parameters), but I don't understand why it shows that error on `User.first`.

Here is what I have:

```
users_controller.rb

  ...
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end


Schema.rb

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end


user.rb (model)

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :lists
  has_many :items, through: :lists
  has_secure_password
```

There is at least a user in the DB. On localhost index, it shows (I am using serializer):

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"name":"Iggy1","email":"letsmailiggy@gmail.com","items":[],"lists":[]}]}
```

I also has `has_secure_password` on model. Could that be the cause? I was not sure if `has_secure_password` is compatible with `Devise`. How can I fix it so I can create user on rails console?

If you need more code snippet, please let me know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password), you can see what `has_secure_password` does:

> Adds methods to set and authenticate against a BCrypt password. This mechanism requires you to have a password_digest attribute.

You don't have the `password_digest` attribute, hence the error.

But the real issue is that if you're using Devise, you don't need `has_secure_password` at all. It is usually used if you want to roll your own authentication, Devise already takes care of encrypting and storing the passwords. Remove it from the model and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I have password_digest at the schema if  you look at it. How can I remove the password digest from schema? Will simply deleting `has_secure_password` remove `password_digest` from schema?

Comment: It won't, the column will still be there in the database, it just won't be used. Make a migration to remove it with something like `remove_column :users, :password_digest`.

Comment: It works! I deleted password_digest (rake db:drop; I already deleted my DB earlier so it's already emptied out), removed the migration containing password_digest, and commented out `has_secure_password`. I can create `User` now :)